# aggrid tree - how to keep tree state (contracted levels) after rowData updated?

Tags: angular7, ag-grid

Is there a way to keep the tree state after rowData is updated? Unfortunately every time I refresh the data and update rowData the state goes back to default (collapsed).

Comment: See [ask], and especially [mcve]. The idea is you describe what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you get. reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily.

Comment: I don't know why the question was downvoted. I'm asking if there is a build it ag-grid event that can help me do this rather than implement it from scratch.

Comment: fyi, I am not the downvoter. but I guess he/she also wants to see live example with the issue

Comment: It's not an issue, this is the way ag-grid is implemented. We are enterprise-level users (pay a lot for the library + support) and StackOverflow has been the way we have been communicating with the company. The library has a ton of "hidden" features and sometimes it is very difficult to find very useful functions.

Comment: The fact that you have paid for ag-grid does not give you the right to ask low quality questions on Stack Overflow. None of your questions on here have been answered by ag-grid employees, it's other developers. It's up to you, but you will greatly increase the chances of your questions getting answered if you write *good questions*. That means include code, a [demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (start from a relevant demo from [the docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation-main/documentation.php)), and a [clear description](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found the answer on the aggrid website:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#keeping-group-state

"When you set new data into the group by default all the group open/closed states are reset. If you want to keep the original state, then set the property"

```
rememberGroupStateWhenNewData=true
```